# Complimenting 101: Hair

Tags: translation, meaning, english-to-german

"You look more beautiful with long hair than before."

I tried but I don't know if my translation is valid. I would say:

> Du siehst aus schöner als vor, mit langen Haaren"

Do I have my words in the right order?

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of the number »101« in the question. What does it mean?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: "101" wird im US-Amerikanischen Gebrauch als stehender Begriff für "eine Einführung in" oder "die wichtigsten Punkte" benutzt. Die engliche Wikipedia hat einen kurzen Abschnitt dazu: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/101_%28number%29#In_education

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mit langen Haaren siehst du schöner aus als vorher.

Comment: "zuvor" may sound odd in some areas; I'd definitely use "vorher", or if the time of reference was long ago (seems like in this context), "früher".

Answer (score 8):

"Mit langen Haaren siehst du schöner aus als zuvor." could be a bit too formal if you want to compliment s.o.

I would rather say "Mit langen Haaren siehst du schöner aus als vorher." But this also implements s.th bad, s.o. could understand "You looked ugly before"

"Mit langen Haaren siehst du noch schöner aus als vorher." is a bit smarter, like "you look like even more beautiful..."

Answer (score 2):

This translation proposal is a bit free, since it does not compare before/after, but this is also presumably not desired as pointed out by @Malibu:

> Lange Haare stehen dir.

(something like: "long hair suits you")